# How to make a div size to match the div content (to create a shadow effect)?

Tags: html, css, sass

I have this html

```
<div class="picture-image">
  <img src="/path/to/img.jpg" alt="" class="img-fluid">
</div>
```

and this css

```
.picture-image {
    height: 100vh;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
}
.picture-image>img {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    object-fit: contain;
}
.img-fluid {
    max-width: 100%;
}
```

in this way the containing div matches the screen size (approximately) and the image matches the height or the width (depending on the orientation) and can resize without stretching.

Now I would like to apply a shadow effect to the image so I was thnking that I need a div for that, but how can I make that div to match the image size and also resize when changing the browser size?

Comment: But there's no *"a shadow effect"* in your CSS for `img` - Also... why `contain` instead of `cover`? That way your image will have no blanks

Comment: cover will cut the image

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use [filter: drop-shadow()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/filter-function/drop-shadow) on the `img` to create a shadow on the **image-data** itself (instead of around the `img`'s bounding box):

```css
/* QuickReset */ * { margin: 0; box-sizing: border-box; }  /* Add this on top */

.picture-image {
  height: 100vh;
  /* overflow: hidden;   /* REMOVE THIS */
  position: relative;
}

.picture-image>img {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: contain;
  filter: drop-shadow(0 5px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3)); /* Add this */
  padding: 20px; /* and this to add some spacing */
}

.img-fluid {
  max-width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="picture-image">
  <img src="https://d5nunyagcicgy.cloudfront.net/external_assets/hero_examples/hair_beach_v391182663/original.jpeg" alt="" class="img-fluid">
</div>
```

Comment: Amazing, I didn't know this property. However you can only see the shadow on the side, how can I add it below? Maybe it is because picture-image hide it at the bottom? Padding does not work.

Comment: yes I tried and it only works for the top.

Comment: if I remove height the image will fill all the picture-image div.

Comment: yes, as I said it only affects the top.

Comment: Could you try [`box-shadow`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-shadow) in place of `filter: drop-shadow`?

Comment: Edited my answer to add some spacing! @user3174311

Comment: @CristianTraìna `box-shadow` will not work because it affects the `img` - not the **image-data**. And the `img` tag is `100% x 100%`

Comment: box-shadow works with padding. thank you.

Comment: @user3174311 resize your window and you'll see `box-shadow` does not work as expected. (and remove overflow: hidden; from the parent to see why.)

Comment: sorry I meant filter: drop-shadow

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan thank you. Do you have any reference for this?